# Using Newton-Raphson method to approximate the minimum value of the function

Tags: matlab, newton-raphson

I am trying to use seven iterations of Newton-Raphson formula to find the minimum value for the following function, with the initial condition x = 4:
$$f\left(x\right)=x^4-3x^3-1$$
For the Newton-Raphson method, the general formula is:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f\:\left(x_n\right)}{f\:'\left(x_n\right)}$$

And below is the Matlab code I wrote for this formula:

```
format long
clear x
x = [4];
iterations = 7;

for n = 1:iterations
    x(n+1) = x(n) - (x(n).^4 - 3*x(n).^3 - 1) ./ (4*x(n).^3 - 9*x(n).^2);
end

minimum = min(x)
```

But it seems my formula isn't correct because I didn't get the expected result, could anyone please point out what is my mistake ? Did I use a wrong formula to find the minimum value or am I supposed to use 'min(x)' to find the minimum value ?

Comment: You should find the root of $f'(x)$.

Comment: The minimum value of a differentiable function $f(x)$ is achieved for an $x$ which a solution to $f'(x) = 0$. Your code is finding a zero of $f(x)$ (which should give something close to $x\simeq 3.0357$). If you redo the analysis with $f\to f'$ so the formula becomes $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f'(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}$ you should get better results (the global minimum is at $x = 9/4 = 2.25$ for which $f(x) = -\frac{2443}{256} \simeq -9.54297$).

Comment: @Winther Thanks, may I ask how did you get $-\frac{2443}{256}$ ?

Comment: @phantom By plugging in $x = 9/4$ in the expression for $f(x)$.

Comment: @Winther Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is for finding the root of $f(x)$, which is not what you want. In fact you should find the root of
$$f'(x)=4x^3-9x^2$$
So the correct iteration formula should be
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f'(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{4x_n^3-9x_n^2}{12x_n^2-18x_n}$$

And by the way, the problem can be solved analytically.